# Why is the values in the database gets deleted after I run the python code?

Tags: python, mysql

I have written the following code to insert the data into my MySQL database. The table has entries that are product,saleprice, and the date as the table headers. The database name is hpsize and the table name is hptable I am adding more rows using the code below.

```
import pymysql
import time

date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 0:0:0')

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='root',
                         password='pwd',
                         db='hpsize')

my_cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO hptable (product, saleprice, date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val = ("Benq", "61",date)

my_cursor.execute(sql,val)
my_cursor.execute("SELECT * from hptable")

result = my_cursor.fetchall()

for i in result:
    print(i)

connection.close()
```

When I run the program, the values ( Benq, 61, date) get updated in the database.  but when I run the same script with another value ( Compaq, 18, date), the previous value is being overwritten or deleted. Why is it happening.

Comment: How is that table defined? Can we see the schema please

Comment: You should try to `COMMIT` your changes.

Comment: @Matthias The problem was indeed committing. Unfortunately, I did not find this in my tutorial.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for offering the help. The problem was that I did not commit.

Answer (score 0):

There is chance that you haven't defined any primary key. Please ensure that

Comment: Thanks for offering the help. The problem was that I did not commit.